# php gd - multicolor imagettftext

Tags: php, gd, truetype, imagettftext

I'm trying to put multicolor text through imagettftext.
I tried drawing letter by letter but the kerning is poor.

Here's my code:

```
$usrname_split = str_split("Text");
$onecharwidth  = imagefontwidth((int)$font)*(12/8);
foreach($usrname_split as $key=>$letter){
    if($key == 0){
        // first letter
        imagettftext($im, 12, 0, $xusrname, 15, $blue, $font, $letter);
        $oldletters = "$letter";
    }else{
        $posarr=imageftbbox(12, 0 ,$font, $oldletters);
        $posx = $posarr["2"];
        imagefttext($im, 12, 0, $posx, 15, $red, $font, $letter);
        $oldletters .= "$letter";
    }
}
```

Is it possible to achieve multicolor text through imagettftext with better kerning?

Answer (score 0):

in order to test, replace your code by this one:

```
 $string="Mario Ermando";
 $last_string= substr( $string, 1 );

        imagettftext($im, 12, 0, $xusrname, 20, $blue, $font, $string[0]);  //first letter "M"
        imagefttext($im, 12, 0, 12, 20, $red, $font, $last_string);
```

[image]

i think the problem is when you write every letter separately

Comment: I have to write every letter separately because the color for every letter must be different.

Comment: Hi, can you add the full code? I am facing the same problem... I have to create image with two colors to a single string. half of the string with one color and another half with second color